# Number of levels in tree

Tags: tree, quicksort

Assume that the partition algorithm partitions the input array of size n into 1:9 ratios constantly. The, determine the total number of levels in the corresponding tree when the size of every sub array is 1.

I used formula of nth term of a GP.We have to find when nth term is 1. Since first term is 9n/10 and common ratio is 9/10 so,

(9n/10)*(9/10)^k-1=1

K=log n/(1-log9)

(Base of log is 10)

If we put n=10, the number of levels are near about 21.

Is this right? Please check, i request all of you humbly.

Comment: What does 1:9 mean when n is not a multiple of 10? How are partitions done for n=5, n=13, n=18, ...etc?

Comment: Theoretically, for n=5 it would be like 0.5 and 4.5 and this keeps going on till 4.5 * 0.9 (several times) becomes 1.    But practically this is not possible.

Comment: So then what is your question, because this case will come in, even if you start with an `n` that is a multiple of 10. What **is** the practical way it works?